# Pull numbers from URL with Regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm receiving urls in the following format:

```
http://www.whatever.com/maybesomthinghere/2323923723?what=what&who=no
```

I'd like some regex to grab "2323923723" from the URL. It may or may not have query string elements appended at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple numbers in a URL to extract:

```
url.scan(/\d+/)  # => ["2323923723"]
```

Or a single one:

```
url[/\d+/]       #=> "2323923723"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `str.delete` like this:

```
num = str.delete("^0-9")
```

Output:

```
[7] pry(main)> str
=> "http://www.whatever.com/maybesomthinghere/2323923723?what=what&who=no\n"
[8] pry(main)> str.delete("^0-9")
=> "2323923723"
```

Comment: Hahaha... Power of Ruby..you misused :-)

Comment: Well ya @ArupRakshit everyone else is going to post the boring responses we all know - how about a curve ball! ;)

Comment: LoL...Enjoy the power of Ruby.

Comment: If next world war begins.. I will use Ruby's power full lambda `->() { }` only.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to capture any sequence of numbers out of the url, then this should work:

```
s = [url]
/[0-9]+/.match(s)
```

If you want to find a sequence of numbers bounded by / and ?, then you'd want something more like:

```
s = [url]
/\/([0-9]+)\?/.match(s)
```

You could be much more specific if you need to verify that you are working with a valid URL, if the numbers need to be bounded by more specific text, etc.

You may want to use rubular (http://rubular.com/) to test interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression since the URL might contain other numbers after the `?` (within the query string) or even before.

```
/(\d+)(?:\?)/
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tS1oP2/1)